# i get this error '' IndexError: list index out of range ''

Tags: python, list, numpy, testing, append

i get this error `IndexError: list index out of range`:

```
ERROR: test_Nullstellen_Polynom (__main__.Test_Praktikum) [Nullstellen des Polynoms p11 werden nicht korrekt mit Parametern delta=10**-5, n=50 berechnet.]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AYMEN\test2.py", line 191, in subTest
    yield
  File "C:\Users\AYMEN\test2.py", line 450, in test_Nullstellen_Polynom
    self.runner(lib.Nullstellen_Polynom, (a, 10**k, n), self.assertAlmostEqualRelativeAbs,
  File "C:\Users\AYMEN\test2.py", line 135, in runner
    result = post(method(*args))
  File "C:\Users\AYMEN\lib2.py", line 147, in Nullstellen_Polynom
    pol=Hornerschema(pol,x_nst[-1])[:-1]
  File "C:\Users\AYMEN\lib2.py", line 95, in Hornerschema
    b.append(a[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

my code:

````
def Hornerschema(a, x0):
   
    i = 1
    b = []
    b.append(a[0])
    while i < len(a):
           b.append ( b[i-1] * x0 + a[i])
           i +=1
    return b

def Polynom_Funktion(a):    
    def p(x):
        n=len(a)
        res=0
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            res+= Hornerschema(a, x)[-1]*x**(n-i-1)
            i +=1
        return res 
    return p
      
def Diff_Polynom(a):
    n=len(a)
    u=list(range(n-1))
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        u[i]=a[i]*(n-1-i)
    return u

def Nullstellen_Polynom(a,delta,k):
   start=-10
   end=10
   n=40
   length=len(a)
   NstL=[]
   pol=a
   trys=n             
   x_nst=[]
   for i in range(length-1):
     while trys>=(n):
          x1=complex(np.random.uniform(start,end), np.random.uniform(start,end))
          f=Polynom_Funktion(pol)
          df=Polynom_Funktion(Diff_Polynom(pol))
          x_nst=Newton_Verfahren(f,df,x1,delta,n)
          trys=len(x_nst)
          pol=Hornerschema(pol,x_nst[-1])[:-1]
          NstL.append(x_nst[-1])
          trys=n
   return NstL``` 
test file:
````

```
def test_Hornerschema(self):
    for i, a in enumerate(self.pi):
        name = 'p' + str(i + 1)
        with self.subTest(msg='Hornerschema für Polynom {} falsch.'.format(name), name=name):
            for x0 in np.linspace(-10, 10, 11):
                self.runner(lib.Hornerschema, (a, x0), self.assertAlmostEqualRelative)
        
def test_Polynom_Funktion(self):
    for i, a in enumerate(self.pi):
        name = 'p' + str(i + 1)
        with self.subTest(msg='Polynom_Funktion für Polynom {} falsch.'.format(name), name=name):
            p = lib.Polynom_Funktion(a)
            for x in np.linspace(-10, 10, 11):
                self.runner(p, (x, ), self.assertAlmostEqualRelative)
        
def test_Diff_Polynom(self):
    for i, a in enumerate(self.pi):
        name = 'p' + str(i + 1)
        with self.subTest(msg='Diff_Polynom für Polynom {} falsch.'.format(name), name=name):
            self.runner(lib.Diff_Polynom, (a, ), self.assertAlmostEqualRelative)
        
def test_Nullstellen_Polynom(self):
    np.random.seed(seed=12345)
    import random
    random.seed(12345)
    for i, a in enumerate(self.pi):
        name = 'p' + str(i + 1)
        with self.subTest(name=name):
            for k, n in ((-5, 50), ):
                with self.subTest(msg='Nullstellen des Polynoms {} werden nicht korrekt mit Parametern delta=10**{}, n={} berechnet.'.format(name, k, n), name=str(-k)):
                    self.runner(lib.Nullstellen_Polynom, (a, 10**k, n), self.assertAlmostEqualRelativeAbs,
                                post=Test_Praktikum.Polynom_von_Nullstellen, true_value=a, relative=10**-4,
                                msg='Polynom {} = {}.'.format(name, a))
```

Comment: The code for `Hornerschema()` you present is not the same as the code you report as giving the error.  There is no line `b.append(k[0])`.

Comment: you r right, it is the same error though. i update the post with the right error

Comment: It seems that the code could legitimately be executed by handing in an empty array as the first parameter to the Nullstellen_Polynom() function, in which case a[0] would cause an index out of range error. Could you update the question with detail of exactly what starts this code running? How is it first called and with what values?